# RabbitMQ combination of topic exchange and RPC works only once

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I'm experimenting with creating a combination of the topic exchange mentioned in [tutorial #5](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html) and RPC mentioned in [tutorial #6](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html), and while it works once, it doesn't work again unless I restart the consumer code.

In the client code, which runs on the machine with the RabbitMQ server, I have register_request() which receives a message (from a higher level made with Flask) and adds it to the exchange based on a routing key, and then waits for a response. The callback reply_queue_callback() adds responses to a dictionary where the keys are the correlation ID.

```
class QueueManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes an exchange and a reply queue.
        """
        self.responses = {}

        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host="localhost"))
        atexit.register(self.close_connection)

        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
        self.channel.exchange_declare(exchange=EXCHANGE_NAME, type="topic")
        result = self.channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
        self.reply_queue = result.method.queue
        self.channel.basic_consume(self.reply_queue_callback, no_ack=True, queue=self.reply_queue)


    def close_connection(self):
        """
        Closes the connection to RabbitMQ. Runs upon destruction of the instance.
        """
        print "*** Closing queue connection..."
        self.connection.close()


    def reply_queue_callback(self, ch, method, props, body):
        """
        A callback that is executed when there's a new message in the reply queue.
        """
        self.responses[props.correlation_id] = literal_eval(body)


    def register_request(self, routing_key, message):
        """
        Adds a message to the exchange.
        """
        corr_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        self.channel.basic_publish(exchange=EXCHANGE_NAME, routing_key=routing_key,
                                   properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                                       reply_to=self.reply_queue,
                                       correlation_id=corr_id),
                                   body=message)
        print "*** Sent request with correlation ID", corr_id
        return corr_id


    def fetch_response(self, corr_id):
        """
        A polling function that waits for a message in the reply queue.
        """
        print "Waiting for a response..."
        while not self.responses.get(corr_id):
            self.connection.process_data_events()

        return self.responses.pop(corr_id)
```

In the consumer's code, which runs on a separate machine, receive_requests() is the main function and request_callback() is the callback function for a new message.

```
def request_callback(ch, method, props, message):
    """
    A callback that is executed when a relevant message is found in the exchange.
    """
    print "Pulled a request with correlation ID %s" % props.correlation_id
    response = produce_response(message)
    print "Produced a response, publishing..."
    ch.basic_publish(exchange="",
                     routing_key=props.reply_to,
                     properties=pika.BasicProperties(correlation_id=props.correlation_id),
                     body=response)
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
    print " [*] Waiting for new messages\n"


def receive_requests():
    """
    The main loop. Opens a connection to the RabbitMQ server and consumes messages from the exchange.
    """
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=RABBITMQ_IP))

    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.exchange_declare(exchange=EXCHANGE_NAME, type="topic")

    result = channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
    queue_name = result.method.queue

    for binding_key in BINDING_KEYS:
        channel.queue_bind(exchange=EXCHANGE_NAME, queue=queue_name, routing_key=binding_key)

    channel.basic_consume(request_callback, queue=queue_name, no_ack=True)

    try:
        print(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C\n")
        channel.start_consuming()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Aborting..."
```

When I produce a message the first time, the consumer handles it and I get a response back, but with the second message it seems that nothing reaches the consumer (the client prints that it added the new message to the exchange, but the consumer doesn't print anything). I assume something's wrong with the consumer, because if after the first message I restart the consumer's code and keep the client running as is, a second message works fine.

Any idea what the problem is? Perhaps I'm missing something in the consumer's callback?

Comment: If you are working with Flask and Pika it might be worth taking a look at my async example here https://github.com/eandersson/python-rabbitmq-examples/tree/master/Flask-examples

Comment: btw you need to continuously process process_data_events - otherwise it will miss critical messages; such as heartbeats.